# Exception Handling in a Layered Application

Tags: c#, .net, exception

If I have a layered application and my Data Layer may encounter an **OptimisticConcurrencyException** how should the calling layer or indeed the lower layer deal with this??

The calling layer has no idea what an **OptimisticConcurrencyException** is, so should I be implementing a custom exception and catching the **OptimisticConcurrencyException** and throwing my Custom Exception?

Some guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OptimisticConcurrencyException` is an exception that belongs to the data layer and should therefore be contained within it. It's unlikely that calling layer could handle it.

I would create a more generic exception such as `DataSourceException` which would contain some context such as which function failed (and with which parameters) and why. I would also include the original exception as inner exception.

Read my blog entry about catching exceptions: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception/

I've also written some other entries about exception handling, click on the Exception tag.

**Update**

I would create the following projects:

- Project.Web *<--- uses service through the specification interfaces.*
- Project.Service *<-- implements everything in Specification*
- Project.Service.Specification *<--- Place exceptions (classes) here and interfaces defining your services (or repositories if you do not use any services).*

Comment: My UI is MVVM, I want my ViewModel to advise the user that the record was updated by another user and perform some navigation accordingly, but what type of exception do I catch? In that layer it would only be able to identify the exception as a System.Exception.

Comment: In this case, create an exception which indicates that the record changed. For instance `EntityChangedByOtherException` or something like that. Follow the Seperated Interface pattern found here: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html to reduce coupling between the layers.

Comment: @jgauffin, thanks again for reply. Are you suggesting that I implement for example EntityChangedByOtherException (which would inherit from System.Exception) in the assembly/layer that would throw it and define an interface for it in another assembly e.g. IEntityChangedByOtherException which my VM would use?

Comment: You can easily change your implementation without affecting your other code by doing it this way. For instance, you start by using Entity Library, but discovers how stale it is and switch to nhibernate.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at this from the perspective of the calling layer.  The layer has asked the data layer to perform a job.  If the `OptimisticConcurrencyException` can be handled by your data layer and the contract adhered to, then by all means catch it and then carry on and complete the job.

If, however, this is fatal to the job you're being asked to do, and if the caller is not expecting it, or doesn't know it, then it's fine for you to create your own exception class, catch the exception that is alien to the calling layer, and throw that instead. This is something that the calling layer *can* know about, and can be well-documented as a side-effect of using this function/API.